# Random number in range [min - max] using PHP

Tags: php, security, random

Is there a way to generate a random number based on a min and max?

For example, if min was 1 and max 20 it should generate any number between 1 and 20, including 1 and 20?

Comment: New php version has a cryptographically secure [random number generator](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31421151/1090562).

Comment: For PHP 7+ use `random_int()`, `random_bytes()`, or `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() `. as @Salvador Dali said `rand()` do not generate cryptographically secure results. See documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

Answer (score 179, accepted):

```
<?php
  $min=1;
  $max=20;
  echo rand($min,$max);
?>
```

Comment: i thought that min and max for rand was the number of digits to use instead of numbers :) thnx

Comment: Related: if `PHP_INT_MAX < ($max-$min)`, you need to add intervals together, as described in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31252637/what-is-phps-mt-rand-minimum-value-and-how-to-calculate-32-bit-interger-on-32).

Comment: rand() before PHP7.1 is simply bad. It uses LCG algorithm which results with predictable output. It is also slow. 
Since PHP7.1 rand() is made an alias of mt_rand() therefore no longer bad.
PHP7 also introduced cryptographically secure random_int(), however it should be avoided unless essential, since it's much slower than mt_rand()

Answer (score 46):

In a new [PHP7](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/easy_userland_csprng) there is a finally a support for a [cryptographically secure pseudo-random integers.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php)

```
int random_int ( int $min , int $max )
```

> random_int — Generates cryptographically secure pseudo-random integers

which basically makes previous answers obsolete.

Comment: That's great! But until webhosts support PHP7 more globally, this is not useful for anyone building products for distribution unfortunately. So the previous answers that ALSO work on PHP7 are still best practice.

Comment: @MattCromwell. I do not agree with you. Until hosting services support PHP7 we should use polyfill for `random_int` and `random_bytes` function - https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat.

Comment: I'm curious, is there ever a reason NOT to use `random_int `? If it gives "better" random numbers, why not use it for non-crypto reasons?

Comment: @BrianLeishman I would rather use it for everything. The only downside that I can guess: it probably relies on the source of randomness and might fail if you are out of randomness. It might be more expensive (need to check) but I doubt that this one function makes a big difference

Comment: I do know that it's slower, but it's insignificant enough to not go back and change already existing `random_int`s to `rand`s. Also, my use case is a retry algorithm, and I definitely don't want multiple failed functions clumping after sleeping because of predictable random ints

Answer (score 22):

A <strike>quicker</strike> faster version would use mt_rand:

```
$min=1;
$max=20;
echo mt_rand($min,$max);
```

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mt-rand.php.

**NOTE:** Your server needs to have the Math PHP module enabled for this to work. If it doesn't, bug your host to enable it, or you have to use the normal (and slower) rand().

Comment: you mean faster right ? the difference is (typing==quicker vs faster==performance wise)

Comment: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/31732/what-is-the-difference-between-quicker-and-faster - actually can be both

Answer (score 9):

I have bundled the answers here and made it version independent;

```
function generateRandom($min = 1, $max = 20) {
    if (function_exists('random_int')):
        return random_int($min, $max); // more secure
    elseif (function_exists('mt_rand')):
        return mt_rand($min, $max); // faster
    endif;
    return rand($min, $max); // old
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
(rand() % ($max-$min)) + $min
```

or

```
rand ( $min , $max )
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

Answer (score 5):

```
rand(1,20)
```

Docs for PHP's rand function are here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

Use the `srand()` function to set the random number generator's seed value.

Answer (score 0):

Try This one. It will generate id according to your wish.

```
function id()
{
 // add limit
$id_length = 20;

// add any character / digit
$alfa = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz1234567890";
$token = "";
for($i = 1; $i < $id_length; $i ++) {

  // generate randomly within given character/digits
  @$token .= $alfa[rand(1, strlen($alfa))];

}    
return $token;
}
```