# PHP: How to display random blocks of text from a multi-dimensional array?

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop

I'm trying to display blocks of text from a list of blocks.

I'm thinking that an array makes the most sense...

```
$quotes[] = array(
    'block'  => 'Luck is what happens when preparation meets Opportunity.',
    'author' => 'Seneca',
);
$quotes[] = array(
    'block'  => 'Quote number two.',
    'author' => 'Author Two',
);
$quotes[] = array(
    'block'  => 'Quote number three.',
    'author' => 'Author Three',
);
```

Now if I wanted to list the quotes I would do this:

```
foreach($quotes[] as $quote) {
    echo '<div><p>"<i>' . $quote['block'] . '</i>"<br />― ' . $quote['author'] . '</p></div>';
}
```

**But how do I go about listing just one of the quotes randomely?**

I was looking around and some people were using `while loops`?

The end goal is that wherever I place this piece of code, I want to display a random quote in different parts of my website, so I don't want the same quote to be in every spot.

Comment: `shuffle($quotes)`; then just `$displayQuote = array_pop($quotes);` and display that one.... [shuffle()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php), [array_pop()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-pop.php)

Comment: How do I display the first one in the shuffled list? I didn't think it would be that simple lol... Every question I read had a mess of math.

Comment: `echo $quotes[array_rand($quotes)];`

Comment: Do you want to put that into a question so I can answer it? -- EDIT: into an answer to I can accept it*****

Comment: That's what I meant.

Comment: Yeah it is a duplicate, not sure how I didn't see that original question before.

Comment: @Dagon I like your method, it's the same as the apparent duplicate answer, but I can't display the quote and the author this way. How do we make this work?

Comment: you have to store the random key picked then use it, like so: `$rand_key=array_rand($quotes); echo $quotes[$rand_key]['block']; echo $quotes[$rand_key]['author'];` Alternative: `$picked =$quotes[array_rand($quotes)]; echo $picked['block']; $picked['author']`

Comment: @Dagon thanks, make an answer so I can accept it please =)

Comment: question is closed, it can't be answered

Comment: @Barmar I believe this question is different than the other one because this also needs to solve the problem of using a multi dimensional array - which the other one didn't show me

Comment: Once you select an element, you have an array that you can use just like any other array.

Comment: @Dagon hey I'm trying to get this working but it's not budging for me, I'm using a php sandbox here http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b4bd4b0f012a2bd6d1bb970ec14ad92837ebbd1b

Comment: It's no different, you're still only selecting an element from the top-level of your $quotes array, it's only the displaying of that element that's slightly different (unless you want to pick a random block and a random author independently)

Comment: @MarkBaker  I understand the question is very similar, not disputing that, just saying that the result is not the same thing.

Comment: your demo is missing the `[]` you use above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's as simple as just getting random integer from 0 to count($quotes).

That could be done like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173867/php-random-number-using-min-max).

In your case:

```
echo $quotes[rand(0, count($quotes) - 1)]['block'];
```

Comment: You're not accessing the properties of `$quotes`.

Comment: True story, bro :0) Edited.