# What is PHP's mt_rand() minimum value and how to calculate 32 bit interger on 32 bit Linux box

Tags: php, linux, random

What is the minimum value allowed for `mt_rand()`?  Is it the same value for 32 bit and 64 bit machines?  How could I generate a 32 bit integer using `mt_rand()` (note that it doesn't need to be highly random)?

BACKGROUND WHY I AM ASKING: I have a 64 bit development physical server and a 32 bit production VPS.  Just realized the production server was not generating PKs spanning the full range.  To figure out what is going on, I ran the following script.  The 64 bit machine never (or at least I've never witnessed) matches, but the 32 bit matches about 50% of the time.

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('America/Los_Angeles');
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

$count=0;
for ($i = 0; $i <= 10000; $i++) {
    $rand=2147483648+mt_rand(-2147483647,2147483647); //Spans 1 to 4294967295 where 0 is reserved
    if($rand==2147483649){$count++;}
}
echo('mt_getrandmax()='.mt_getrandmax().' count='.$count);
```

output

```
mt_getrandmax()=2147483647 count=5034
```

Comment: ` generating PKs` - PKs==private keys? As in "asymetric key pairs"?

Comment: @VolkerK  PK=database table Primary Key which is public.  Many would argue that it need not even be random and that an auto-incrementing PK should be used and a few would argue that a highly random PK should be used, however, I dare not ask such an opinionated question :)  My only purpose is so the PK doesn't advertise the age of the record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**TL;DR: To get a random integer in the full range of possible integers, use:**

```
function random_integer() {
    $min = defined('PHP_INT_MIN') ? PHP_INT_MIN : (-PHP_INT_MAX-1);
    return mt_rand($min, -1) + mt_rand(0, PHP_INT_MAX);
}
```

For PHP 7, you can use [`random_int()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php).

---

Under the hood ([1](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/rand.c#L338), [2](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/php_rand.h#L45)), PHP is doing this:

```
$number = random_number_between_0_and_0x7FFFFFFF_using_Mersenne_Twister;
$number = $min + (($max - $min + 1.0) * ($number / (0x7FFFFFFF + 1.0)));
```

Notice `$max - $min`.  When max is set to the top end and min is anything negative, an overflow occurs.  Therefore, the maximum *range* is `PHP_INT_MAX`.  If your maximum value is `PHP_INT_MAX`, then your minimum is necessarily `0`.

Now for the back story.  PHP implements the 32-bit Mersenne Twister algorithm.  This gives us random integers between [0, and 2^31-1).  If you ask for any other range, PHP *scales* that number using a simple binning function.  That binning function includes a subtraction that can lead to overflow, and this problem.

Thus if you want to get a range larger than could be represented by an integer in PHP, you have to add intervals together, like so:

```
mt_rand(PHP_INT_MIN, -1) + mt_rand(0, PHP_INT_MAX);
```

Note that `PHP_INT_MIN` is available since PHP 7, so you'll need to calculate a suitable minimum for your environment before then.

---

As an aside, notice that 2^31-1 is what `getrandmax()` returns.  People mistakenly believe that on a 64-bit machine `getrandmax()` will return 2^63-1.  That's not true.  `getrandmax()` returns the maximum integer the *algorithm* will return, which is always 2^31-1.

Answer (score 2):

You can generate a 32 bit integer like this:

```
$rand = unpack("l", openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(4));
```

Comment: Question is why you are wasting 32 BYTES if all you need are 32 BITS?

Comment: Indeed. Changed to 4 bytes. :)

Comment: My need for randomness is very low, and I didn't wish to incur the server overhead required for `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()`.  See my comment under my original post.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem that is noted in the PHP docs over here

> This works fine on 64 bit Linux:
>
> ```
>   <?php
>      printf ("%08x\n", mt_rand (0, 0xFFFFFFFF));
>    ?>
> ```
>
> but on our 32 bit Linux development server, it's always yielding `00000000`.
>
> On that same machine, this:
>
> ```
> <?php
> printf ("%08x\n", mt_rand (0, 0xFFFFFFF0));
> ?>
> ```
>
> seems to always yield either `00000000` or a number in the range `fffffff2` to `ffffffff`. This:
>
> ```
> <?php
> printf ("%08x\n", mt_rand (0, 0xFFFFFF00));
> ?>
> ```
>
> gives numbers where the last two digits vary, and so on through at least `0xF0000000.`
>
> However, this:
>
> ```
> <?php
>    printf ("%08x\n", mt_rand (0, 0x7FFFFFFF));
> ?>
> ```
>
> works fine

A bug report is added [here](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=70003).

There has been no word whether PHP is fixing this yet.

In the meantime you can use the `mt_rand` function between the `max_rand` and you should be fine

**Example Usage**

```
$rand=mt_rand(1,2147483647)+mt_rand(0,2147483647);
```

Comment: Thanks Carl,  I was planning on doing something like your proposed solution if I couldn't find a better one.  My main concern was I didn't know this was occuring, and I do think the PHP documentation should be updated.

Comment: I agree. I found this while digging through all the comments from users at the bottom. My hope is they fix it in the next release

Comment: Am I missing something?  The maximum of `mt_rand` is [2**31](https://marc.info/?l=php-internals&m=142889549207950&w=2), based on the very [definition in code](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/php_rand.h#L48)

Comment: I'm confused. 2**31 is 2147483648

Comment: Sorry mean to say 2**31 *minus* one, ie: `(1 << 31) - 1` and `0x7FFFFFFF`. :)

Comment: Heads up, there is a [patch](https://github.com/php/php-src/compare/master...bishopb:prevent-rng-overflow) fixing these reported bugs.  Let me know if those patches fix in your environment.