# Full randomization with PHP (you could use for Casinos)?

Tags: php, random, hash, numbers

How can I get fully randomized numbers from a PHP script?

Comment: [random_int](http://php.net/manual/en/function.random-int.php)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041509/generate-cryptographically-secure-random-numbers-in-php

Comment: Yeah how about you take a quick tour how to [ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and maybe you try out this gorgeous tool named [google](http://www.google.com)

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "fully randomized". If you want true random numbers, you'll have to use a specialized hardware or an external service; "normal" computer hardware can't generate true randomness.

Comment: Just by typing "PHP random number" in a web search yields thousands of results with readily usable scripts which you can just copy + paste & modify. Try consulting a good PHP manual, like SAMS PHP in 24 hours.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Random number in range \[min - max\] using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4173867/random-number-in-range-min-max-using-php)

Answer (score -1):

`mt_rand()` should do it (PHP5 code).

`random_int()` works only starting with PHP7.

Comment: You can use `random_int` in PHP 5 too, [with a polyfill](https://packagist.org/packages/paragonie/random_compat).

Comment: @Paulpro: Unless he has good reasons why he needs cryptographically secure random integers, I wouldn't suggest to blow your application code with unnecessary packages. His question sounds to me like he just wants to have a random integer.

Comment: `mt_rand` is a PRNG not a CSPRNG. It definitely couldn't be used "for casinos". It also takes only a few seconds to add `random_compat` as a project dependency and keeps the code future proof.